# How can i stop my tableView cell from reusing the button inside it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, swift-protocols

I have a function inside a protocol that takes a TableViewcell as an argument.

```
protocol GoingButtonDelegate {
    func goingButtonPressed(cell: TableViewCell)
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var goingButton: UIButton!

    var delegate: GoingButtonDelegate?

    @IBAction func goingButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.goingButtonPressed(cell: self)  
    }
```

I then go over to my ViewController and implement the delegate and it's function, which is to change the image of a button when tapped. The "goingSelected" is a green image and the "goingDeselected" is a red image.

This all works out fine, when tapped the button of a cell goes from red to green and vice versa. However, when the cell gets reused, the button state of the cell persists and gets reused for the new row that enters view. Is there any way to stop this from happening?

```
 extension ViewController: GoingButtonDelegate {
    func goingButtonPressed(cell: TableViewCell) {
        cell.goingButton.isSelected = !cell.goingButton.isSelected

        if cell.goingButton.isSelected == true {
            cell.goingButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "goingSelected"), for: UIControlState.selected)
        } else if cell.goingButton.isSelected == false {
            cell.goingButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "goingDeselected"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent UITableView from reuse custom cells Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938809/how-to-prevent-uitableview-from-reuse-custom-cells-swift)

Comment: You do not want to avoid reusing cells. That's not the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible

just replace

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier,
  for: indexPath)
```

with:

```
let cell= Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(identifier, owner: self, options: nil)?[0]
```

but I think you need to change your app logic.

Set `Images` inside of your cell class

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.goingButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "goingDeselected"), for:.normal)
    self.goingButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "goingSelected"), for:.selected)
  }
}
```

and in method `goingButtonPressed(cell: TableViewCell)` change `cell` to your object
and just set `Bool` type true or false

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  ...
  cell.goingButton.isSelected = object.isSelected
  ...
}
```

Comment: You do not want to do this. Do not avoid reusing cells.

Comment: @rmaddy I already provide answer that better will be change logic

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the selected rows in an array of index paths, before that I think you should make few enhancements ... or a lot!!

the cell itself should handle it's button, the controller should just keep track of all cells status. 
Add these two properties to your cell

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var indexPath:IndexPath?
    var isSelected : Bool = false {
        didSet{
            if isSelected {
                cell.goingButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "goingSelected"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            } else {
                cell.goingButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "goingDeselected"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
        }
    }
    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var goingButton: UIButton!

    var delegate: GoingButtonDelegate?

    @IBAction func goingButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.isSelected = !self.isSelected
        delegate?.goingButtonPressed(cell: self)  
    }
    ..
    ...
}
```

And store the selected cells in your view controller to keep track of each cell status.

```
extension ViewController: GoingButtonDelegate {
    var selectedCells = NSMutableArray()
    func goingButtonPressed(cell: TableViewCell) {
        if cell.isSelected {
            selectedCells.add(cell.indexPath)
        } else {
            selectedCells.remove(cell.indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

and in your "cell for row" method just add a small change

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourCellIdentifier") as! TableViewCell
    cell.indexPath = indexPath
    cell.isSelected = selectedCells.contains(indexPath)
    ..
    ...
    return cell
}
```